# Correct dates that have been lost continuity

Tags: python, pandas, date

I came to you for help. The thing is that we have a database (1.2 million records) that keeps track of the monthly payment dates of our clients, but due to an error the dates have been set to the first payment date of each client. (I give an example below)

```
    user    fec

0   a   2016-12-08
1   a   2016-12-08
2   a   2016-12-08
3   a   2016-12-08
4   a   2016-12-08
5   b   2017-07-22
6   b   2017-07-22
7   b   2017-07-22
8   b   2017-07-22
9   b   2017-07-22
10  c   2017-04-13
11  c   2017-04-13
12  d   2018-11-26
13  d   2018-11-26
14  d   2018-11-26
```

and now we try to correct them so that it looks as follows

[image]

To be honest I don't know how to addres this, if there is someone here who can guide me, I will appreciate it

Comment: Please include your data and expected output  as text. Also, what happens if you have data like `31/8/2016 31/8/2016 31/8/2016`?

Comment: I was thinking the same so I found pd.date_range(), so here I can put my initialdate for a user, then manage periods as the len() of records with the user id and the freq as M for monthly and this manage to solve the problem you say. So now I need to find a way apply this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to add 1 month to each consecutive date per user, you can do something like this:

```
import datetime
import calendar
import pandas as pd

df['fec'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fec'])

def add_months(sourcedate, months):
    month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
    year = sourcedate.year + month // 12
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)


df['fec'] = df.groupby('user')['fec'].agg(list).apply(lambda x: [add_months(x[0], i) for i in range(len(x))]).explode().values
```

output:

```
   user         fec
0     a  2016-12-08
1     a  2017-01-08
2     a  2017-02-08
3     a  2017-03-08
4     a  2017-04-08
5     b  2017-07-22
6     b  2017-08-22
7     b  2017-09-22
8     b  2017-10-22
9     b  2017-11-22
10    c  2017-04-13
11    c  2017-05-13
12    d  2018-11-26
13    d  2018-12-26
14    d  2019-01-26
```

though, that nasty one-liner might be possible an easier way, or can be broken into steps

NOTE - depends on pandas v1.0.5+

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to shift all the date to month-end:

```
df['fec'] = (df.groupby('user')['fec']
               .transform(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.min(), freq='M', 
                                                  periods=len(x))
                         )
            )
```

Output:

```
   user        fec
0     a 2016-12-31
1     a 2017-01-31
2     a 2017-02-28
3     a 2017-03-31
4     a 2017-04-30
5     b 2017-07-31
6     b 2017-08-31
7     b 2017-09-30
8     b 2017-10-31
9     b 2017-11-30
10    c 2017-04-30
11    c 2017-05-31
12    d 2018-11-30
13    d 2018-12-31
14    d 2019-01-31
```